FOB Poker: Probability of a sequence of numbers (with the existence of "wild-card" number)
At work we have 2 factor authentication using a fob that generates a sequence of 6 numbers 0-9. We started playing "poker" by having everyone generate a number at the same time and see who has poker type hands with the number sequence. There are some differences: Poker has a fixed deck so "numbers" do not repeat, but the fob repeats numbers obviously. We make the zeros "wild." There are 6 instead of 5 values. Therefore, we do not know how to rank some of the "hands."
2 questions:
(1) Do these differences effect the probability of the standard (5 value) "poker" hands?
(2) How do I calculate the probability of "hands" utilizing the 6th digit ( 3 pair, two triples, straight of 6 numbers, 6 of a kind,... etc.)?
I would like to generate a "hand" ranking table to quell some arguments.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

The answer to (1) is "yes", the changes affect the probabilities

There are $10^6$ potential fob sequences.  This may be small enough to use brute force counting, though complicated by the wild cards.

I got the following probabilities. They are counted so that if a sequence satisfies multiple hands, it is counted in all categories (for example 3-of-a-kinds are also 2-of-a-kinds).
6-of-kind: 71/125000        = 0.0005680000
5-of-kind: 161/12500        = 0.0128800000
3-3-of-kind: 1837/100000    = 0.0183700000
4-2-of-kind: 841/40000      = 0.0210250000
6-straight: 8231/200000     = 0.0411550000
4-of-kind: 2869/25000       = 0.1147600000
2-2-2-of-kind: 11719/100000 = 0.1171900000
5-straight: 16927/100000    = 0.1692700000
3-2-of-kind: 7321/40000     = 0.1830250000
4-straight: 20399/50000     = 0.4079800000
3-of-kind: 11959/25000      = 0.4783600000
2-2-of-kind: 110693/200000  = 0.5534650000
3-straight: 140789/200000   = 0.7039450000
2-of-kind: 2936/3125        = 0.9395200000
2-straight: 190831/200000   = 0.9541550000

At least the 6-of-kind should be correct as it is
$$
\frac{9\cdot 2^6 - 9 + 1}{10^6} = \frac{71}{125000}
$$
(There are $2^6$ sequences of zeros and some other value $x \in \{1,2,\dots, 9\}$, but the all-zeros sequence it counted 9 times.)
Here's the Sage-code I used (basically Python, but the Partitions() and Compositions() functions are there) Takes about 5 minutes to run:
#represent hand as {number: how many of that}
#for wilds, check all possible ways they can be intepreted

def doHands(n, d=10):
    def genHands():
        #if there are m wilds, the rest is then a composition of n-m (allowing 0's)
        #there are n!/(m!*prod(k!)) ways to have this hand
        for m in range(n+1):
            for rest1 in Compositions(n-m+d-1, length=d-1):
                coef = factorial(n)/prod(factorial(k-1) for k in rest1)/factorial(m)
                yield coef, m, {j+1: rest1[j]-1 for j in range(d-1)}
    
    def genWilds(m):
        for t in Compositions(m+d-1, length=d-1):
            yield {j+1: t[j]-1 for j in range(d-1)}
    
    def joinHands(h1, h2):
        return {j: h1[j]+h2[j] for j in range(1, d)}
    
    
    def hasParts(h, parts):
        b = sorted(h.values(), reverse=True)
        if len(b)<len(parts): return False
        for j,p in enumerate(parts):
            if p>b[j]: return False
        return True
    
    def hasRun(h, r):
        maxRun = 0
        currRun = 0
        for j in range(1, d):
            if j in h and h[j]>0:
                currRun += 1
                if currRun > maxRun:
                    maxRun = currRun
            else:
                currRun = 0
        return maxRun>=r
    
    
    #---Put the possible hands and their checkers in a dictionary------------------
    checkers = {}
        
    for j in range(2, n+1):
        for parts in Partitions(j, min_part=2):
            pName = "-".join(str(p) for p in parts) + ("-of-kind")
            checkers[pName] = lambda c, parts=parts: hasParts(c, parts)
    
    for r in range(2, n+1):
        checkers[str(r)+"-straight"] = lambda c,r=r: hasRun(c,r)
    
    #-- Let's start counting ------------------------------------------------------
    tot = 0
    cs = {hand: 0 for hand in checkers}
    
    for coef, wilds, h in genHands():
        tot += coef
        for hand,checker in checkers.items():
            if any(checker(joinHands(h, h2)) for h2 in genWilds(wilds)):
                cs[hand] += coef
    return {hand: cs[hand]/tot for hand in cs}


testN = 6
testD = 10
%time ps = doHands(testN, testD)
hands = sorted(ps.keys(), key=lambda h: ps[h])
print ("\n\n  For %d cards, using digits 0-%d \n" %(testN, testD-1) )
for h in hands:
    print ("%s: %s = %.10f" %(h, ps[h], ps[h]))

